# MailKit in winautomation V8 does not accept Arabic letter

Tags: mailkit, mimekit

In Winautomation V.7 I could write arabic letters in filds but in winautoamtion V.8 it give me this Error
but if I write English letter or left it blank it accept it.

[this Error when I put Arabic letter like "عد"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Led3h.png)
and in logs event typs I find this message

```
Failed to filter messages on mail-folder "INBOX"
MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapCommandException: The IMAP server replied to the 
'SEARCH' command with a 'NO' response: The specified charset is not 
supported.
at MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapFolder.Search(SearchQuery query, CancellationToken 
cancellationToken)
at WinAutomation.Actions.Runtime.EmailActions.RetrieveEmails(Variant 
imapServer, Variant username, Variant varPassword, Variant mailFolder, 
Variant fromContains, Variant toContains, Variant subjectContains, Variant 
bodyContains, Variant sentSince, Variant sentUpTo, Variant 
saveAttachmentsInto, Variant& retrievedEmails, Int32 serverPort, Boolean 
enableSsl, Boolean passwordDirectly, String password, Boolean 
retrieveOnlyUnread, Boolean saveAttachments, Boolean markAsRead)"
```

but If I left it blank or write any English letter it accept it 
[here i add the word "rest"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfpQE.png)
in old version of winautomation it accept any letter in Arbic or english>

Answer (score 2):

This error happens when the IMAP server only supports US-ASCII.

If you get a [protocol log](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#ProtocolLog), you should be able to see a list of charsets that the server supports in the error message.

I'm 100% certain that it will list only US-ASCII as a possible charset and that's why you are getting this error.